# HSSFRichTextString styles not applied for cell with default values

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am newbie to POI but facing strange issue.Appreciate any quick help.

I have template xls in which font for each cell is set to Arial (Font -size : 6.5).
In My application I am generating new excel report by using above default template.

```
Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(InputStream s);
```

As a result new excel acquired all properties(font styles) specified in My template xls.

Now when i write to particular cell using HSSFRichTextString its styles are not applied.
Say in cell containing text & number I want to make text as Arial & Numbers as Terminal. E.g SS 123
SS: Arial, 123: Terminal.
But as my cell has default font style as Arial everything in cell is written as Arial Only. 
Although when i select & inspect 123 in cell its depict font as Terminal but ion reality applied font is Arial Only.

```
private static HSSFRichTextString formatNumbersOfCellText(String outputString,Font numberFont, Font strFont){
    HSSFRichTextString formattedString = null;
     try{
        if(null != outputString &&               !outputString.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            int lstIndexCalculated=0;
            int startIndex ;
            int endIndex;
            String[] splittedArr = outputString.split("\\s");
            if(null != splittedArr && splittedArr.length > 0){
                formattedString = new HSSFRichTextString(outputString);
                for (int i = 0; i < splittedArr.length; i++) {

                        if(lstIndexCalculated == 0){
                            startIndex =       outputString.indexOf(splittedArr[i]);
                        }else{
                            startIndex = outputString.indexOf(splittedArr[i],lstIndexCalculated);
                            if(lstIndexCalculated < startIndex){
                                formattedString.applyFont(lstIndexCalculated,startIndex ,numberFont);
                            }
                        }
                        endIndex   = startIndex + (splittedArr[i].length());
                        lstIndexCalculated = endIndex;
                        if(isNumericField(splittedArr[i])){
                            formattedString.applyFont(startIndex,endIndex ,numberFont);
                        }else{
                            formattedString.applyFont(startIndex,endIndex ,strFont);
                        }
                        startIndex = 0;
                        endIndex   = 0;

                }
                if(lstIndexCalculated != 0){
                    return formattedString;
                }
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
      return null;   
    }
    return null;

}
```

Now If I give formatting to only one substring then it works fine.

```
 RichTextString richString = new HSSFRichTextString( "SS 123 SS" );
 richString.applyFont( 0, 3, font1 );
 cell.setCellValue( richString );
```

This works fine but in below case where iterating more than once gives issues

```
 RichTextString richString = new HSSFRichTextString( "SS 123 SS" );
 richString.applyFont( 0, 3, font1 );
 richString.applyFont( 3, 6, font2 );
 richString.applyFont( 6, 9, font1 );
 cell.setCellValue( richString );
```

[Valid style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHzBV.png)
[My incorrect xls style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZfs6.png)

As you can see in 1st link (valid style) for Terminal font there is under-strike for character '1'.
But in Arial there is no under-strike for character '1'. So this is the expected behaviour.
But in my case as in 2nd link (My incorrect xls style) even if 213.27 is shown by ribbon as Terminal font it is not. see diff between character '1' in image.
This is what I am referring to

Please help. I am completely blocked due to it.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: "Now when i write to particular cell using HSSFRichTextString its styles are not applied. " Please show code how you do that. Btw.: https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#RichText

Comment: formattedString.applyFont(startIndex,endIndex ,strFont);                                  Where start/end index are substring for which i have to apply particular font

Comment: Hey after further analysis found that MS Excel does`t apply  that styling to content. But when I do print preview i can see Rich text styling applied to content. Any specific reason ??

Comment: Provided code in my answer works for me without issues using recent final `apache poi` version 3.15. Which issues are you having? In other words: Please describe the problems you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are doing wrong.

Supposing `Source.xls` like this:

[image]

Code like this:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRichTextString;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

class ReadAndWriteRichText {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {

   InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("Source.xls");
   Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);

   Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
   Row row = sheet.getRow(0);
   Cell cell = row.getCell(0);

   Font font1 = wb.getFontAt(cell.getCellStyle().getFontIndex());
   System.out.println(font1);

   Font font2 = wb.createFont();
   font2.setFontName("Terminal");
   font2.setFontHeightInPoints(font1.getFontHeightInPoints());
   System.out.println(font2);

   RichTextString richString = new HSSFRichTextString( "SS 123 SS" );
                                                      //^0 ^3 ^6 ^9
   richString.applyFont( 0, 3, font1 );
   richString.applyFont( 3, 6, font2 );
   richString.applyFont( 6, 9, font1 );
   cell.setCellValue( richString );

   FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("Target.xls");
   wb.write(fileOut);
   wb.close();

  } catch (Exception ex) {
  }
 }
}
```

will result in `Target.xls` like this:

[image]

As you see 123 is in font `Terminal`.

---

According your updated question I provide a code which should work as wanted:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRichTextString;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

class ReadAndWriteRichText {

 private static boolean isNumeric(String string) {
  try {  
   double d = Double.parseDouble(string);  
  } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {  
   return false;  
  }  
  return true;  
 }

 private static RichTextString formatNumbersOfCellText(String outputString, Font numberFont, Font strFont) {

  RichTextString richString = new HSSFRichTextString(outputString);

  String[] tokens = outputString.split("\\s"); // splits on a single space, so possibly empty strings are in the array

  int start = 0;
  int end = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
   String token = tokens[i];
   end = start + token.length();

   if (i < tokens.length - 1) {
    end = end + 1; // if not the last token, then take one character more than the length because of formatting the split-delimiter-space after the token
   }

   if (isNumeric(token)) {
    richString.applyFont(start, end, numberFont);
   } else {
    richString.applyFont(start, end, strFont);
   }
   start = end;
  }

  return richString;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {

   InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("Source.xls");
   Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);

   Font font1 = wb.createFont();
   font1.setFontName("Arial");
   font1.setFontHeightInPoints((short)26);

   Font font2 = wb.createFont();
   font2.setFontName("Terminal");
   font2.setFontHeightInPoints((short)26);

   Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

   for (Row row : sheet) {
    for (Cell cell : row) {
     String cellValue = cell.getStringCellValue(); // all cells must be text cells
     RichTextString richString = formatNumbersOfCellText(cellValue, font2, font1);
     cell.setCellValue(richString);
    }
   }

   FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("Target.xls");
   wb.write(fileOut);
   wb.close();

  } catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex for sample code.  I have added my code to above question for applying Rich Text formatting to contents in my cell.

Comment: I tried but still no luck. After selecting text/number excel shows respective font as being applied, but in reality only ARIAL font is applied. Though when I do print preview I see correct formatting.

Comment: There is a difference between the font of the whole cell (which is shown in the ribbon when selecting the whole cell) and the fonts of the rich text runs within the cell (which are shown in the ribbon when editing the cell and then depended on cursor position or partly selection). The fonts of the rich text runs are there but they are not shown if the whole cell is selected.

Comment: Yes Alex. In edit mode itself based upon cursor position it shows that Terminal font is applied for numbers. But in reality its not terminal Its Arial only in my case.

Comment: "But in reality its not terminal Its Arial only": The question is what we take as "the reality" then ;-). If it is shown as Terminal in ribbon and will be printed as Terminal, then I would take this as the reality. Why you are thinking it is not Terminal then?

Comment: I Have updated my question. Attached few images (as link) so explain my issue. Please go through them. Thanks

Comment: Sorry cannot reproduce, apache poi 3.15 final, Excel 2016. Thought it could have be something to do with line breaks in cells. But even with line breaks my code works for me and Excel shows Terminal font in its GUI view also.

Comment: Axel finally I got the cause. My xls zoom % is set to 120 & font size for terminal is 6.5. on this configuration I am facing the issue. When I change font size to 7 then I can see desired formatting. :) I also generated excel using above your code snippet. On 100% zoom I can see formatting but when u reduce zoom % to 70 you can reproduce the issue. Any Idea why ? Is this limitation with POI HSSFRichtext ?

Comment: "Is this limitation with POI HSSFRichtext?" Surely not. apache poi is only generating the file. As long the file content is correct, it is not to blame for how Excel's GUI will show it. This is a limitation with Excel's GUI view. Btw.: Font sizes lower than 8pt fulfills the condition of the bodily injury in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah it seems limitation with excel GUI only.,Finally glad to know that there`s no issue with my code. anyways Thanks for all the vital information Alex. And yeah Thanks for bearing with me (as i said I am newbie to POI.)